# Twitter Bootstrap - Update Affix Data-Offset attribute on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, sticky-footer

I am using a "sticky footer" technique for an area on the page which also has a navbar utilizing affix. The problem is the data-offset attribute needs to get updated depending on where the sticky footer is - thus it cannot be hard-coded.

How to I get the value in pixels of where the sticky footer is, and pass that value into the data-offset attribute so it knows when to affix itself?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am also fixing navbar depending on position that cannot be hardcoded into css. Not because of an sticky footer, but just space above navbar (when not fixed) is dynamic, but I suppose the solution is similar.

I am using JavaScript to fix/unfix by setting/unsetting proper classes dynamicaly depending if some DOM element is visible on viewport. The scheme is as follows:

- navbar is styled with `position: absolute` and the space containing it has static height of navbar, so there is no change of position of a content below when fixing,
- bind the function that spies the scrolling and fixes navbar if the element above is not visible,
- check if element is visible by comparing the bottom of its position with the top of position of the viewport,
- fix/unfix by adding/removing bootstrap classes each time the user scrolls or change the size of window.

The code in [Opa framework](http://www.opalang.org) (converting to JS+jQuery should be straightforward as Opa's DOM library is just simple binding to jQuery):

```
// id of the element above the navbar, and the navbar
logobar_id = "logo-bar";
navbar_id = "main-menu";
// hardcoded height of the navbar
navbar_height_px = 30;

client function distance() {
  dom = #{logobar_id};

  // hardcoded height of the navbar
  win = Dom.select_window();

  // position of the top of the viewport
  scroll_visible = Dom.get_scroll_top(win);

  // return the distance between of bottom of element above the navbar and the top of 
  dom_bottom = Dom.get_offset(dom).y_px + Dom.get_height(dom);
  dom_bottom - scroll_visible;
}

dom = #{navbar_id};

private client function fixation() {
  if (distance() <= 0) {
    // TODO: remember if subnav is fixed, dont fix if fixed
    Dom.add_class(dom, "navbar-fixed-top");
    Dom.remove_class(dom, "container");
  } else {
    // TODO: remember if subnav is fixed, dont unfix if unfixed
    Dom.remove_class(dom, "navbar-fixed-top");
    Dom.add_class(dom, "container");
    void;
  }
}

// (un)fix when scroll
private client function onscroll(_) {
  fixation();
}

// bind the `onscroll` handler for subnav when it is loaded
private client function onready(_) {
  _ = Dom.bind(Dom.select_window(), {scroll}, onscroll);
  fixation();
}
```

The DOM element above the navbar and the navbar itself:

```
<div class="container" id=#{logobar_id}>
  My logo with dynamic content
</div>
<div class="container" style="height: {navbar_height_px}px; position: relative; top: 0px">
  <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px">
    <div class="navbar container" id=#{navbar_id} onready={onready}>
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```